# Rename case sensitive item

Tags: powershell

I am trying to rename a folder with the same name but different case. Consider this simple code:

```
Rename-Item -Path C:\files -NewName C:\Files
```

Returns the error 'Source and destination path must be different.'

Also I have tried this:

```
$item = 'C:\files'
Rename-Item -Path $item -NewName ($item.Name -replace 'files', 'Files')
```

Which does not work. Also the `-force` parameter does not help.

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: I believe you need an intermediate step to a temporary name as file and folder names on Windows are case insensitive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is still a two step, but it's a one-liner:

```
Rename-Item C:\files -NewName Files-Temp -PassThru | Rename-Item -NewName Files
```